# How to add to existing JSON.stringify string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, xmlhttprequest

Am I able to add to this string once it has been stringified.

For example, here is the array I start with:

```
var headers = {
 'Dropbox-API-Arg' : JSON.stringify({
    'close':false,
    'cursor': {
       'session_id': '',
       'offset': chunk.offset
    }
  })
}
```

I have the session_id back from the server in another variable called responseText, how do I add that var as the session_id value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First parse the JSON string, so you can update values via Javascript. After that you can turn it into a JSON string again.

```
const obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

obj.cursor.session_id = sessionId;

const str = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse, add data, re-stringify.

```
let o_daa = JSON.parse(headers['Dropbox-API-Arg']);
o_daa.cursor.session_id = '<whatever>';
headers['Dropbox-API-Arg'] = JSON.stringify(daa);
```

As an alternative approach, consider not to store the stringified API call arguments in the `header`structure but stringifying on-the-fly when you issue the Ajax call which would free you from the need of repeatedly parsing and stringifying the API call arguments.

Comment: I'd love to but I have to make 3 different calls to 3 different endpoints for which the headers are different. So I set them up at the beginning. The only reason I need to do this is because the 2nd and last calls require a response (session_id) from the first call.